# Array of numbers to array of ranges between min and max price with difference

Tags: arrays, ruby, range

I have an array `prices`:

```
[1399, 1435, 1465, 1715, 1745, 1760, 1825]
```

I want an array of ranges between the min and the max price with the difference of `100`. I need something like:

```
[1399..1499, 1499..1599, 1599..1699, 1699..1799, 1799..1899]
```

Is there a one-liner?

Comment: What have you tried so far, post your attempts

Comment: I can create a loop and then manually increment until max value.
I am just looking for some ruby built in one liner.
I also tried following but it is of no use in my case.
(array_of_prices + [Float::INFINITY]).each_cons(2).map { |a,b| a..b }

Comment: You have changed the question. Don't do that! If you change a question after an answer has been posted, it could, as here, make the answers inon-sensical at best. Instead, post another question. In fact, it's not clear what you now want. If the array were `[1399, 1715, 1825]` would you want the same array of five ranges returned (in which case only the smallest and largest elements of the array would matter).?

Comment: Should the prices always end in `99` or does it depend on the array's first value – i.e. if you had a minimum value of `1325`, would the first range be `1325..1425` or `1299..1399`?

Comment: depends on the array's first value. would be 1325..1425

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`step`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Numeric.html#method-i-step) by your `n` (in this case, 100):

```
array = [1399, 1435, 1465, 1715, 1745, 1760, 1825]
array.min.step(to: array.max + n, by: n).each_cons(2).map { |a, b| a..b }
# => [1399..1499, 1499..1599, 1599..1699, 1699..1799, 1799..1899]
array << 1899
array.min.step(to: array.max + n, by: n).each_cons(2).map { |a, b| a..b }
# => [1399..1499, 1499..1599, 1599..1699, 1699..1799, 1799..1899, 1899..1999]
```

Note that `step` doesn't pass any value that's greater than `to:` to the block, so if you increment your largest value by `n` things seem to work out.

Comment: `arr.min.step(by:n, to: arr.max).map { |i| i..i+n }` may suffice.

Comment: Accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
n = 100
arr = [1399, 1435, 1465, 1715, 1745, 1760, 1825]

start = arr.first
arr.slice_before do |x|
  if x > start + n
    start = x
    true
  else
    false
  end
end.map { |f,*_| f..f+n }
  #=> [1399..1499, 1715..1815, 1825..1925]
```

The third range in the returned array differs from that desired in two respects. The third range was asked to be `1815..1825`. I assume `1815` was a typo, as if differs from the logic for the second range. If it desired that the end of the last range should be the last element of `arr`, rather than the first element of the range plus `n`, that's just a bit of messiness to fix. It could be done as follows.

Let

```
a = [1399..1499, 1715..1815, 1825..1925]
```

as computed above. Then

```
a[0..-2] << (a.last.begin..arr.last)
  #=> [1399..1499, 1715..1815, 1825..1825]
```

Comment: Note my answer was to the question as originally posted.